# Map generic list to MongoDB using Morphia

Tags: java, mongodb, generics, morphia

I want to map generic object that contains generic list to MongoDB using MongoDB Java driver (v3.4.2) and Morphia (v 1.3.2), like this:

```
public class KPI<T> {

    public ArrayList<T> kpiList;
}
```

I used

```
Morphia morphia = new Morphia();
morphia.map(KPI.class);
```

To map the class and when I try adding an instance of KPI called *someKPIObject* object to Mongodb using

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(addr);
AdvancedDatastore datastore = (AdvancedDatastore) morphia.createDatastore(mongoClient, "myDB");
datastore.insert(myDoc,someKPIObject);
```

I get following error:

> **WARNING: Parameterized types are treated as untyped Objects. See field
>   'kpiList' on class KPI
>   org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.MappingException: 
>   Error mapping field:KPI.kpiList**     at
>   org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.Mapper.toDBObject(Mapper.java:984)    at
>   org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.Mapper.toDBObject(Mapper.java:593)    at
>   org.mongodb.morphia.DatastoreImpl.entityToDBObj(DatastoreImpl.java:1362)
>     at org.mongodb.morphia.DatastoreImpl.insert(DatastoreImpl.java:1227)
>     at org.mongodb.morphia.DatastoreImpl.insert(DatastoreImpl.java:1046)
>     at mongoconnector.MongoConnector.AddNewEntry(MongoConnector.java:97)
>     at Parser.main(Parser.java:31)
>
> **Caused by:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Generic TypeVariable not supported!**     at
>   org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.MappedField.toClass(MappedField.java:639)
>     at
>   org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.MappedField.getSubClass(MappedField.java:313)
>     at
>   org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.EmbeddedMapper.shouldSaveClassName(EmbeddedMapper.java:29)
>     at
>   org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.EmbeddedMapper.writeCollection(EmbeddedMapper.java:242)
>     at
>   org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.EmbeddedMapper.toDBObject(EmbeddedMapper.java:90)
>     at
>   org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.Mapper.writeMappedField(Mapper.java:876)
>     at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.Mapper.toDBObject(Mapper.java:982)
>     ... 6 more

What am I doing wrong, and is it even possible? I use Java 1.8.

Answer (score 0):

Morphia does not support save generics in the DB, so, you can try to make a simple interface and then make all classes you want to save implement it, or something like that.

They have open issues related to your issue  [1](https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/issues/737) ,  [2](https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/issues/925)

Also, which Morphia/MongoDB/Java version you use ?

Comment: I edited question with versions of libraries. I know there are open issues, but interface wouldn't work for me.